# Importing files from PostgreSQL to R

Tags: r, postgresql

I have a large data-set and I will preform some analysis in R software.
While I could not import the data properly to R.

I get this error:

```
Error in postgresqlNewConnection(drv, ...) : RS-DBI driver: (could not connect User@local on dbname "Intel"
```

I have used PostgreSQL to open data and somehow manage it. How can I import the existing data in the PostgreSQL to the R software?

Comment: Isn't that possible with the PL/R language ? http://www.joeconway.com/plr/

Comment: It would help if you explained what happens when you try to import it. If possible show specific error messages. I've copied the one error message you showed in a comment into the question.

Comment: Honestly, I have not hear PL/R before. As I mentioned I have large amount of data that should be analyzed in R but R could not handle it. I have used Navicat and Pg-admin to prepare data. In order to import prepared data to R, I want to use "RPostgreSQL package" and based on descriptions, I used "drv <- dbDriver("PostgreSQL")" and then "con <- dbConnect(drv, dbname="tempdb")" code did not run and following error arose.  [Error in postgresqlNewConnection(drv, ...) : RS-DBI driver: (could not connect User@local on dbname "Intel"].

Answer (score 25, accepted):

```
drv <- dbDriver("PostgreSQL")
con <- dbConnect(drv, host='localhost', port='5432', dbname='Swiss',
                 user='postgres', password='123456')
```

Moreover, "RPostgreSQL" package in R should be installed.

Answer (score 7):

Try the R package RPostgreSQL http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RPostgreSQL/ .
You can see how to use it in http://code.google.com/p/rpostgresql/ .
Example:

```
library(RPostgreSQL)
drv <- dbDriver("PostgreSQL")   ## loads the PostgreSQL driver
con <- dbConnect(drv, dbname="R_Project")   ## Open a connection 
rs <- dbSendQuery(con, "select * from R_Users")   ## Submits a statement
fetch(rs,n=-1)   ## fetch all elements from the result set
dbGetQuery(con, "select * from R_packages")   ## Submit and execute the query
dbDisconnect(con)   ## Closes the connection
dbUnloadDriver(drv)   # Frees all the resources on the driver
```

Comment: Actually, I had seen that before but i face by this error "Error in postgresqlNewConnection(drv, ...) : 
  RS-DBI driver: (could not connect User@local on dbname "Intel""

Comment: I have not used PostgreSQL before. I don't know what is the problem with it.

Answer (score 0):

You have to configure two things on the PostgreSQL server before you are able to connect remotely. This is a instruction how to configure this under Linux:

## 1. Find and configure postgresql.conf to allow the TCP service to accept connections from any host, not only localhost

> find / -name "postgresql.conf"

In my linux OS the file is locate in /etc/postgresql/9.6/main/, so I modify it there. Add the line **"listen_addresses = '*'"** as follows:

> /etc/postgresql/9.6/main/postgresql.conf

```
#listen_addresses = 'localhost'         # what IP address(es) to listen on;
# insert the following line
listen_addresses = '*'
```

## 2. Find and configure pg_hba.conf to allow to connect with a client from any host

> sudo find / -name "pg_hba.conf"

In my linux OS the file is locate in /etc/postgresql/9.6/main/, so I modify it there. Add the line **"host all all 0.0.0.0/0"** as follows:

> sudo nano /etc/postgresql/9.6/main/pg_hba.conf

```
# Put your actual configuration here
# ----------------------------------
#
# If you want to allow non-local connections, you need to add more
# "host" records.  In that case you will also need to make PostgreSQL
# listen on a non-local interface via the listen_addresses
# configuration parameter, or via the -i or -h command line switches.
#
# insert the following line
host all all 0.0.0.0/0 trust
```

## 3. Stop and start the server

> sudo service postgresql stop
>
> sudo service postgresql start

## 4. Connect with you client, now it should work.

GOOD LUCK!