# Want to Connect redshift to R

Tags: r, amazon-web-services, jdbc, odbc, amazon-redshift

I tried to use the code from [this link](https://blogs.aws.amazon.com/bigdata/post/Tx1G8828SPGX3PK/Connecting-R-with-Amazon-Redshift) but I got an error

> driver <- JDBC("com.amazon.redshift.jdbc41.Driver", "RedshiftJDBC41-1.1.9.1009.jar", identifier.quote="`")
>   JavaVM: requested Java version ((null)) not available. Using Java at "" instead.
>   JavaVM: Failed to load JVM: /bundle/Libraries/libserver.dylib
>   JavaVM FATAL: Failed to load the jvm library.
>   Error in .jinit(classPath) : JNI_GetCreatedJavaVMs returned -1

After loading the driver and trying to connect. I don't know how to connect Redshift to R.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will not solve the error, but if you want to connect to Redshift from R, you can use **RPostgreSQL** library.
as in the answer in [another R-Redshift connection issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20788108/cant-connect-to-aws-redshift-using-rpostgresql)

```
library (RPostgreSQL)
drv <- dbDriver("PostgreSQL")
conn <- dbConnect(drv, host="your.host.us-east-1.redshift.amazonaws.com", 
             port="5439",
             dbname="your_db_name", 
             user="user", 
             password="password")
```

You also need to make sure that your IP is Redshift security group white list.