# Connecting to a Redshift database from R

Tags: r, amazon-redshift, rodbc

I want to connect to a database on Redshift and load a table to a data frame

I have the following:

- Hostname (not JDBC URL)
- Username
- Password
- Table name
- Schema

What packages should I use?

I am looking for the right code if someone can help. Should I use RODBC or any other package?

Answer (score 2):

```
brew install libpq

install.packages('RPostgres')
library(RPostgres)
pconn_r <- dbConnect(RPostgres::Postgres(),
               host = host,
               port = port,
               user = user,
               password = password,
               dbname = dbname,
               sslmode='require')
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [RJDBC](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RJDBC/index.html) package.

More details can be found on the official Amazon's [site](https://blogs.aws.amazon.com/bigdata/post/Tx1G8828SPGX3PK/Connecting-R-with-Amazon-Redshift).

See also [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35706832/want-to-connect-redshift-to-r).